# Django - custom userprofile NoSuchTable error

Tags: python, django

I'm writing an app in django. I wanted to add some custom fields to User model.

I've been following this guide:

http://www.tangowithdjango.com/book/chapters/login.html

Login works fine, but while executing register method my website throws

> OperationalError at /register/  no such table: mun_userprofile

Model:

```
from __future__ import unicode_literals
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.db import models

# Create your models here.
class UserProfile(models.Model):
    #Link
    user = models.OneToOneField(User)
    #Extras
    adress = models.CharField(max_length = 50, blank = True)
    city = models.CharField(max_length = 50, blank = True)
    zip_code = models.CharField(max_length = 5, blank = True)

    #Override
    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.user.username
```

Forms:

```
from mun.models import UserProfile
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django import forms

class UserForm(forms.ModelForm):
    password = forms.CharField(widget=forms.PasswordInput())

    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ('username', 'email', 'password')

class UserProfileForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = UserProfile
        fields = ('adress', 'city', 'zip_code')
```

Register method:

```
def register(request):
    context = RequestContext(request)
    registered = False

    if request.method == 'POST':
        user_form = UserForm(data=request.POST)
        profile_form = UserProfileForm(data=request.POST)

        if user_form.is_valid() and profile_form.is_valid():
            user = user_form.save()
            user.set_password(user.password)
            user.save()

            profile = profile_form.save(commit=False)
            profile.user = user
    -->>>   profile.save() ######## Error is thrown at this line #######
            registered = True
        else:
            print user_form.errors, profile_form.errors

    else:
        user_form = UserForm()
        profile_form = UserProfileForm()

    return render_to_response(
            'mun/register.html',
            {'user_form': user_form, 'profile_form': profile_form, 'registered': registered},
            context)
```

I tried to do migrations. I deleted my sqlite db and it stil doesn't help. Any idea why this happens?

Comment: You can check the SQL Query generated, and see if that table is there or not. Possibly you're hitting some other database? So you should check the DB configuration also.

Answer (score -1):

I fixed it. My mistake was that i assumed that

> python manage.py migrate

and

> python manage.py makemigrations

will do everything for me. As it turned out i had to use

> python manage.py makemigrations appname
>
> python manage.py migrate

and now it works.

Silly mistake.

Comment: I don't think this has a strong reasoning behind it, as `python manage.py makemigrations appname` generates migrations only for the specified `appname` while `python manage.py makemigrations` generate for all of your apps listed in `INSTALLED_APPS`. You should run `makemigrations` first, than `migrate`. If you did the inverse (just like you stated in your answer) that might be a better reasoning.